# Translate a triangle using animation(one by one after some interval) with opengl and c++

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, glut

I want to make a space invader game in opengl. So I thought of creating the enemies using triangles. Before making the game, I want to try out my hand in animation. I have triangle. i want to translate it left upto some point with animation(i.e, triangle is translated after some interval of time. It should look as if it is moving).After reaching some point in the left, I want to translate it back to the same position or some distances right. The process should go on till the screen is open. I used sleep function. But it is not working. No animation is shown. Only the translated triangle is drawn at different translated position. Help me.

Here is my code-

```
#include "windows.h"
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void init( void )
{
    printf( "OpenGL version: %s\n", (char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    printf( "OpenGL renderer: %s\n", (char*)glGetString(GL_RENDERER));

    //Configure basic OpenGL settings

    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,640.0,0.0,480.0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glPointSize(3);
}

void house(int x, int y,int z)
{
  glPushMatrix();
  glTranslatef(x, y,z);
  glBegin (GL_LINES);    
     glVertex2i (0,30);
     glVertex2i (15,60);
      glVertex2i (15,60);
       glVertex2i (30,30);
        glVertex2i (30,30);
        glVertex2i (0,30);
        glEnd();
        //Sleep(200);
  glPopMatrix();
    //glutSwapBuffers();
}


// Main drawing routine. Called repeatedly by GLUT's main loop
void display( void )
{
    //Clear the screen and set our initial view matrix

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);


    int i;
    for(i = 10; i < 350; i = i + 50)
  {
    house(i,20,0);
    Sleep(200);
  }

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
 glFlush();

}

// Entry point - GLUT setup and initialization
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

   glutInit( &argc, argv );
   glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_SINGLE| GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowSize (800, 600);
   glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
   glutCreateWindow( "OpenGL Test" );

   glutDisplayFunc( display );


   init();

   glutMainLoop();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main()` you have declared your `display()` as [display callback function](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html).  GLUT will call this function either when it determines that the window need to be redrawn or when it is told to redraw it for example by the function `glutPostRedisplay()`.

The display function is expected to call redraw the windows at a specific point in time.  The [`glFlush()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glFlush.xml) will force the execution of the GL commands.

The problem is that your animation loop is inside the redraw function and `glFlush()` is called at the end, showing the result at once. And you don't tell GLUT to redraw the windows. This is why you don't seee the animation.

For the purpose of the tutorial,  I propose you to define a global variable for the initial position of the house drawing.  Of course, you'll have to improve this as soon as you understood how all this works.

```
static int pos = 10;    // temporary work around, just for the demo
```

Then define a timer function, that gets called after a time interval.  This will be the core of your animation, organizing the moving, and the redrawing of the window by calling  [`glutPostRedisplay()`](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node20.html) :

```
void timerfunc(int value)    // handle animation 
{
    pos += 50;               // update the postion 
    if (pos<350)             // as in your originial loop 
        glutTimerFunc(200, timerfunc, 0);  // plan next occurence
    glutPostRedisplay();     // redraw the window
}
```

[Activate your timer function](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html#SECTION000819000000000000000), in `main()` just before launching `glutMainLoop()`:

```
glutTimerFunc(200, timerfunc, 0);       // call a timer function 
glutMainLoop();                      // this call is already in your code
```

Your display function can then be changed into:

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    house(pos, 20, 0);   // draw the house at its last calculated position 
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFlush();
}
```

Then it works in animated modus !

Comment: can you please provide me some algorithm or code for doing this? Also this is for one triangle.How I will translate array of triangles?

Comment: Thanks....I will see it.If I have a tile of triangles,i.e,triangles arranged as tiles(using viewport  and world window),then how will I move move those tiles left and write just like enemies in space invader. Can you please give me some hints?